# How to use the OpenCV c++ with VSCODE

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code

Base on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4372qtZ4dc
I am trying to use OpenCV in vscode but I canot include the, .lib files what should I do

[image]

#### main.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

  if( argc != 2)
  {
    cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  Mat image;
  image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

  if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
  {
      cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
      return -1;
  }

  namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
  imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

  waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
  return 0;
}
```

#### I get this error

> PS C:\Users\giorg\Documents\Development\Tests\node-addons-test\src\examples> g++ *.cpp
>   main.cpp:1:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>                                    ^
>   compilation terminated.

I manage to include the dlls but I can't find how I can include the files with .lib extension.

this is my c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/lib",
                "C:\\openCV\\opencv\\build\\include",
                "C:\\openCV\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib"  <=== this is the problem , how to include this
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17134.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use cmake by adding a CMakeLists.txt, and it's also cross-platform and easy to use.
I use VS Code, too. And I recommend to use cmake.

Comment: Can you show me how to use cmake with opencv i have installed but i never used. Can you show an example ?

Comment: You can install opencv by homebrew using command `brew install opencv` . 
then you can using the following CMakeLists,txt.
`
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

set(PROJECT_NAME TestOpenCVCmake)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(TestOpenCVCmake main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
`

[Here](https://vvingerfly.github.io/tutorial/2018/03/21/CV-macOSConfigureOpenCV/) is my blog about it. But it's in Chinese.

Comment: here is the link of my post

https://vvingerfly.github.io/tutorial/2018/03/21/CV-macOSConfigureOpenCV/

Hope it helps.

Comment: @LeeDavid - that link is now broken: could you update it?

Comment: @WillC  hi, the link is https://vvingerfly.github.io/2018/03-21-CV-macOSConfigureOpenCV/

Answer (score 0):

to include the .lib files you should acces the properties of your project =>linker=>entries=>additional dependencies then add your .lib file[properties of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOfEf.png)

Comment: Thanks, @niskh but this is with the visual studio setup, how I can do the same with vscode

Comment: try changing the includePath like this : "includePath": [
                "C:/openCV/opencv/build/include",
                "C:/openCV/opencv/build/x64/vc15/bin",
                "C:/openCV/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib",
                "opencv_world341.lib"
            ],

Comment: Nop is not working but thanks. omg I am trying this for 3 days

Answer (score 0):

When you are using CMake, it's not important what editor/IDE you are using.
there are many ways to add an external library in CMake:

1. using **FindPackage**
2. using **submodule**
3. using **manually add the .h/.hpp and lib(dll/so/a/lib) files to your project**
4. and even more

one of the easiest method for adding an external lib to your project is submodule. just search about submodule and learn it, then you can easily use any library inside your project.

Here is a .cmake file that you can use it for submoduling easier
https://www.scivision.dev/cmake-git-submodule/

and a tutorial on it here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210703145609/https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/