# Build OpenCV application with MSVS compiler in VSCode

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, linker

I'm trying to build my C++ project in VSCode. However, I'm experiencing link issues with OpenCV "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol". I've build all the libraries I use with vcpkg.

I build using this .bat file:

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" (
    call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
) else (
    call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
)
set compilerflags=/Od /Zi /EHsc /std:c++latest /I include /I C:\includes\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include
set linkerflags=/OUT:bin\main.exe
cl.exe %compilerflags% src\*.cpp /link %linkerflags% /LIBPATH:C:\includes\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib
del bin\*.ilk *.obj *.pdb
```

My tasks.json file is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build C++ project",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "command": ".\\build.bat"
        },
        {
            "label": "Build & run C++ project",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "command": ".\\build.bat && .\\bin\\main.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

My launch.json file is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Debug (Windows)",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "Build C++ project",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

and finally my settings.json file is:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe"
}
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to properly link vcpkg libraries with VSCode using the MSVS compiler. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51564772/176769
However, that question still doesn't have a credible up-voted answer. Hopefully my answer changes that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently installed **OpenCV 4.3.0** **(64bits)** on Windows 10 and had to configure a workspace in **Visual Studio Code** (VSC) to build a simple application.

The following configuration uses the x64 version of `cl.exe`, the C/C++ compiler that ships with **Microsoft Visual Studio 2019** (Community Edition) to build the OpenCV application.

Pay attention to the paths defined on this `tasks.json` file because they might be different in your system:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "windows": {
        "options": {
            "shell": {
                "executable": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
                "args": [ "/d", "/c" ]
            }
        },
        "isShellCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "echoCommand": true,
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build_vs2019",
            "type": "shell",    
            "windows": {
                "command": "call \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat\" && cl.exe",
                "args": [
                    "/Zi",
                    "/EHsc",
                    "/Fe:",
                    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                    "${file}",
                    "-I", "C:\\opencv\\build\\include",
                    "/link", "/libpath:C:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib", "opencv_world430.lib"
                ],              
                "problemMatcher": [ "$msCompile" ],
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "run",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": [ "build_vs2019" ],
            "windows": {
                "command": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "args": [ "superDark.jpg" ],
                "options": {
                    "env": {
                        "PATH": "C:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\bin"
                    }
                }
            },  
            "presentation": {               
                "reveal": "silent",
                "clear": true,
                "showReuseMessage": false,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This configuration must be used to replace the one in your workspace. It will give you two options to select from when attempting to run tasks:

[image]

- **build_vs2019**: defines the shell as `cmd.exe` and executes `vcvars64.bat` to setup the environment variables and paths that let you use the x64 version of `cl.exe`. It also specifies the headers and required libraries to build an OpenCV-based application. This option builds the application.
- **run**: depends on the success of the previous task to run the OpenCV application on the cmd-line. It adjusts the `PATH` environment variable to point to OpenCV DLLs directory. This option executes the application.